# Game Center report in iOS 7 (Deprecated)

Tags: ios7, game-center-leaderboard

My IDE show warning `"Obsolete: Deprecated in iOS 7.0"` this methods:

- (GKScore) ReportScore()
- (GKAchievement) ReportAchievement()

This methods it works on iOS 7, but use not problem? 
Exist other methods on iOS 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to report score in game center and it works.

```
-(void)reportScore
{
    if(isIOS7)
    {
        // Create a GKScore object to assign the score and report it as a NSArray object.
        GKScore *score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
        score.value = _score;

        [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"score reporting error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"score reported.");
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:_leaderboardIdentifier];
        scoreReporter.value = _score;
        scoreReporter.context = 0;

        [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            // Do something interesting here.
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"score reporting error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"score reported.");
            }
        }];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C methods start with a lower-case method. They are not called with rounded brackets. So, I:

1. opened the documentation for `GKScore`;
2. looked for anything deprecated and found `-reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:`;
3. saw that `+reportScores: withCompletionHandler:` isn't deprecated.

And saw pretty much the same thing with the singular instance method being deprecated in favour of the collection class method in `GKAchievement`.

So: just use the collection methods. Deprecated methods hang around being unsupported for a while and then disappear. You can find out what's currently supported, very very quickly, by reading the documentation.